# Когда и зачем нужно наследовать собственные исключения?

Tags: php, ооп, классы, исключения, наследование

Здравствуйте.

Смотрел исходники SDK для написания ботов в Телеграме ([irazasyed/telegram-bot-sdk](https://github.com/irazasyed/telegram-bot-sdk)) и не в первый раз замечаю, как авторы различных библиотек наследуют какое-то одно исключение, которое затем наследует класс `Exception`. Вот пример из этого SDK:

```
<?php

namespace Telegram\Bot\Exceptions;

/**
 * Class TelegramOtherException.
 */
class TelegramEmojiMapFileNotFoundException extends TelegramSDKException
{
}
```

В данном случае наследуется класс [`TelegramSDKException`](https://github.com/irazasyed/telegram-bot-sdk/blob/master/src/Exceptions/TelegramSDKException.php), а затем это исключение уже наследует класс `Exception`:

```
<?php

namespace Telegram\Bot\Exceptions;

/**
 * Class TelegramSDKException.
 */
class TelegramSDKException extends \Exception
{
}
```

Объясните, пожалуйста, зачем так делают и какие от этого профиты? Почему бы сразу не наследовать класс `Exception`?

Спасибо.

Comment: Странно, я вижу тут как раз-таки то, что вы и хотите. В начале создается собственный класс, унаследованный  от `Exception` то есть `TelegramSDKException extends \Exception` а потом все кастомные идут потомками от него `TelegramEmojiMapFileNotFoundException extends TelegramSDKException`

Comment: Ну как зачем, к примеру вам в ошибку нужно вложить какую-то побочную информацию, которая будет передаваться всегда, чего нет в классе \Exception, не будете ж вы каждый раз засовывать одинаковый код в расширяемый класс, вместо это вы создаете свой MyException, кладете в него нужную вам постоянную инфу, и далее расширяетесь от него

Comment: Чтобы, например, среагировать на исключение только конкретного типа.

Comment: @Visman, получается, если сработает исключение `TelegramEmojiMapFileNotFoundException`, то я смогу его отловить как `TelegramSDKException`? То бишь я смогу отлавливать все исключения этого SDK через один лишь `TelegramSDKException`?

Comment: Как минимум профит будет от того, что в `TelegramSDKException` могут поместить кастомные методы/свойства, специфичные для продукта.

Comment: @terron, сможете, если до этого его не поймает другой обработчик. Вот http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/54c02175fcc8696ec62b4bcb1e86f94171c1b6d5 сначала так запустите, а потом уберите комментарий и еще раз.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Я не спрашивал специально у разработчиков, когда видел такие случаи, но насколько понимаю, это сделано для того, чтобы на высоком уровне ловить исключения конкретной подсистемы.

Допустимы, вы пишете большое приложение, которое в конце обработки отправляет результат в телеграм. У вас не так много времени, чтобы написать идеальное приложение, поэтому вы действуете по принципу working code first и быстрыми шагами движетесь к MVP. Когда архитектура устаканивается, вы понимаете, что у вас миллион вызовов под капотом, но в случае, если уведомление в телеграм не ушло - это плохо, но сама логика приложения выпонилась (e.g. какой-нибудь заказ). В этом случае ваш код может выглядеть так:

```
$warnings = [];
try {
    $orderMachine->issueOrder($orderStub);
} catch (TelegramSDKException $e) {
    $warnings[] = ['exception' => $e, 'message' => 'Could not notify end user via Telegram'
}
// продолжение обработки
```

Кроме того, это позволяет ловить и преобразовывать ожидаемые исключения в работе приложения (e.g. упала сеть - плохо, но ожидаемо) и не ловить те исключения, которые не должны произойти (исключения неправильного использования кода, RuntimeException, ArgumentException и другие - которые явно говорят о том, что библиотека неправильно используется):

```
try {
    $outcome = $this->container->get('orderApi')->issueOrder($orderStub);
    $this->render('::success.html.twig', ['outcome' => $outcome]);
    return 200;
} catch (TelegramSDKException $e) {
    $this->render('::backing-service-failure.html.twig', ['exception' => $e]);
    return 502;
    // RuntimeException не будет пойман и успешно уйдет в обработчик верхнего уровня, где сгенерирует корректную ошибку 500
}
```

Иногда требуется объединить таким образом несколько типов исключений, i.e. вам нужно отнаследоваться и от RuntimeException, и от Exception так, чтобы их можно было словить в одном catch-блоке. Тут вам поможет хак с пустым интерфейсом:

```
interface TelegramSDKExceptionInterface {}

class TelegramConnectivityException extends Exception implements TelegramSDKExceptionInterface {}

class TelegramInvalidMethodInvocationException extends RuntimeException implements TelegramSDKExceptionInterface {}

try {
    ...
} catch (TelegramSDKExceptionInterface $e) {
    // yay!
}
```